# In Zathura, is it possible to correctly show a pdf with mixed page orientation?

Tags: zathura

Running Zathura 0.5.4, when opening a pdf that has mixed page orientation (some pages landscape, some portrait), Zathura will not correctly display the pages.

It will stick with whatever the first page is, and when it comes to a page with different orientation, simply cut off the content that doesn't fit.

Is it possible to fix this?